# Wrong IP when issuing nslookup - Windows DNS Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, nslookup

I recently setup a Windows Active Directory server for Home use. (for learning purposes) Now I have the following problem when using nslookup on a connected client:
http://s17.postimg.org/vcfivvmkf/DNS_Failure.png (not allowed to post images :()

As visible in the picture above, the returned values are not correct. When looking up serverfault.com, it returns my own public IP address (that's why I blurred it), instead of 104.16.46.232. Ping works fine:

http://s9.postimg.org/xwqvbo427/DNS_Failure_Ping.png (not allowed to post images :()

Can anyone help me out? I really don't know what I misconfigured on my DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start by understanding how nslookup works. You issued an unqualified query (no . at the end), so the result you got is what I would expect. Try your query as such: `serverfault.com.` (notice the . at the end?). That's a fully qualified nslookup query.
2. I don't understand what you mean by the statement `Local domain: corp.mydomain.nl (it's not actually mydomain.nl, you get the idea ;))` - Is mydomain.nl your domain or not? If it's not then stop using it.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know nslookup worked that way after all. Great help!

Comment: Glad to help...